# [ARM]How does this checksum code works and how to revert it in C?

Tags: assembly, debuggers, arm

I am trying to reverse a simple code that gets a string and calculates it's checksum. I've been trying to understand every instruction, but they look different from what is said in arm documentation. 
Here's the full code(Using no$gba debugger)
[image: Pink signals the checksum code]

I've reached the code knowing that once the checksum has been calculated it is stored in the r0 register. [Docs](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0068b/BABGIEBE.html) specify that EOR receives 2 args, while here is taking 4.
***eor  r3,r3,r0,asr 8h*** I've figured out that this will be something like  ***r3 = (r3^r0)>>8***  but I'm not really sure. In addition, C/C++ doesn't specify if the >> operator performs arithmetical or logical shifts (asr)

Same confusion is created with the mov's instructions. The sub inst. would be reversed in something like ***r2--; or r2=r2-1;***

Thanks for your time.

EDIT: The checksum is 2 bytes long, and I am giving some examples:

String: AAAAAAB  -- Checksum: 0xB649 (While debugging, write in little endian)

String: AAAAAAA  -- Checksum: 0x68BC 
(NOTE: Checksum can't be worked out by performing operations with different checksum samples)

Comment: How exactly do these instructions look different from the ones in your documentation? "They are all lowercase"?

Comment: @RadLexus ... " Docs specify that EOR receives 2 args, while here is taking 4. eor r3,r3,r0,asr 8h "  From the ARM documentation: Syntax
eor Rd, Rm   Rd->destination  Rm->Second operand

Comment: You are looking at the Thumb documentation, but this code is in [the regular mode](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0068b/BABGIEBE.html) (you can see that because the opcodes are 4 bytes long)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A disassembler and decompiler like *Ghidra* can be used to obtain a C equivalent code.

Also, as specified by @RadLexus, the ARM documentation can be found here: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0068b/BABGIEBE.html